# Accessing Firebug Net tab data from JavaScript

Tags: firebug

Is it possible to access the data found on Firebug's Net tab from JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I consume Firebug net panel data programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497276/how-can-i-consume-firebug-net-panel-data-programmatically)

Comment: @MattBall Thanks for pointing that one out.  I hadn't seen it.  However, it seems to be asking a broader question than mine.  I'm specifically interested in what can be done from JavaScript on the page itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, firebug is not part of the DOM...